# Google Analytics API: how to get non-US visitors

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been using visitors with ga:country filters to get specific country's visitors. For example to get the number of visitors from US, I used the filter of 'ga:country==United%20States'. But I am wondering if I can do something like 'ga:country!=United%20States'? I guess I can subtract ga:country==United%20States from total visitors but I am wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easet way of doing this is to create a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) ga:country.  A filter will let you remove a subset of the data returned by a query.  Think of it like a where clause in SQL.

```
Filter=ga:country!%3DUnited%20States
```

That translates to

```
Filter=ga:country != United States
```

I made a simple report on my personal dashboard the Google Analtyics to test it.

[image]

---

Added info on filtering:
You can add more then one filter by seprateing

```
OR operator is defined using a comma (,).
AND operator is defined using a semi-colon (;).
```

You can mix and match Metric and Dimensions in the same filter.